# Does $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ have a horizontal asymptote?

Tags: asymptotics, graphing-functions

I recently came across a definition of an asymptote of a function as follows:

1. The function gets infinitely close to the asymptote.
2. The function does not cross the asymptote.

This made me wonder whether $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has an asymptote at y = 0, as it fits condition 1 but does not fit 2.
I looked it up, and different sources give different results.

Does $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ have a horizontal asymptote at y=0?
And if so, what is the problem with this definition? Is it an oversimplification or completely incorrect?
And if not, why is that so, as it fits the definition: "a line that a function approaches as x approaches infinity"?

(Also, it would be great if you could list a few reputable sources, but you don't have to.)

Comment: If the definition of asymptote requires both 1. and 2. to be fulfilled, then $y=0$ is not an asymptote, as you stated correctly. Personally (and this lacks a citation), I have not seen 2. as a requirement, and 1. would satisfy the definition of "asymptote" in my opinion. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#General_definition) defines Asymptotes the same way.

Comment: That being said, I would not be surprised if different sources used slightly different definitions, depending on the purpose.

Comment: This additional requirement 2 is not standard.

Comment: It depends on the definition.  $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $y=0$ clearly fail the condition 2 you quote, and this was part of the original definition and etymology of ἀ-σύμ-πτωτος (literally *not together fallen*).  But modern usage typically does not have condition 2.

Comment: I would have thought it needs to not _touch_ an asymptote, otherwise every tangent at a global extremum would be an asymptote.

Comment: The formulation of 1. leaves room for ambiguity. I would rephrase it as: "$f$ approaches $g$ asymptotically as $x\to \infty$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x) - g(x)| = 0$."

Answer (score 0):

The definition I'm familiar to, regarding real valued function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is the following

> We say that $y = l$, where $l\in \Bbb R$, is an horizontal asymptote for $f(x)$ if
> $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = l$$

Analogous formulation for $-\infty$. As you can see this represent the first one of your condition, but the second isn't necessary. Here's graph of the function $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$

[image]

And as you verify by yourself the function intersect $y = 0$ (multiple times) but horizontal asymptote still exist!

---

**P.S.** This example is quite importante because one could think that this behaviour on infinite closeness should happen at least monotonically, instead as the name suggest we are interested in this
asymptotic approach.